# How to create a Uri from an Android resource with file extension

Tags: java, android, android-intent, resources, attachment

I am trying to send a png file in my res/drawable folder as an attachment in my email.  I can get the file to attach and be included in the email, but it is missing the .png file extension.  I want it to include the extension in the file name. Can someone help?  Here is my code:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Text");
            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.png_image);
            uris.add(newPath);

            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(ShareActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to this:

```
i.setType("image/png");
```

Although I believe `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` is not necessary. `putExtra()` should do the job.

Comment: That makes it so that my email client knows it is a png file, but the extension is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get the extension of the file

```
public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String extension;

    //Check uri format to avoid null
    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        //If scheme is a content
        final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
    } else {
        //If scheme is a File
        //This will replace white spaces with %20 and also other special characters. This will avoid returning null values on file name with spaces and special characters.
        extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());

    }

    return extension;
}
```